# Using laravel browsershot

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, laravel-snappy, browsershot

I installed Browsershot and I'm taking google's image to test it. I prepared the route but it gives an unexpected error.

Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException
The command "C:^\nodejs^\node ^"C:^\Users^\AT08877^\it-graph^\vendor^\spatie^\browsershot^\src/../bin/browser.js^" ^"^{^^"url^^":^^"http:^/^/127.0.0.1:8000^/chart^^",^^"action^^":^^"screenshot^^",^^"options^^":^{^^"type^^":^^"png^^",^^"path^^":^^"C:^^\Users^^\AT08877^^\it-graph^^\public^^\deneme.png^^",^^"args^^":^[^],^^"viewport^^":^{^^"width^^":800,^^"height^^":600^}^}^}^"" failed. Exit Code: 1(General error) Working directory: C:\Users\AT08877\it-graph\public Output: ================ Error Output: ================ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdtemp 'undefined\temp\puppeteer_dev_chrome_profile-XXXXXX'] { errno: -4058, code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'mkdtemp', path: 'undefined\temp\puppeteer_dev_chrome_profile-XXXXXX' }

```
Route::get('/test',function ()
{
    $browser = Browsershot::url('www.google.com')
    ->setNodeBinary("'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node'")
    ->setNpmBinary("'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node'")
    ->bodyHtml();
    dd($browser);
});
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow aleyn! did the exception accompanied by an error message? if yes, please add it on the question. i guessed its a windows permission issue due to the `php` can execute something under Program Files. though, its just a guess without the actual error message.

Comment: @BagusTesa I updated the post, can you check it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$browser = Browsershot::url('www.google.com')->setIncludePath("C:\Programs\\nodejs\\node.exe")->bodyHtml();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.